# `Nullpointer within io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport` when using given.post()

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm building an integration-test using restAssured and Junit, and when calling the following code:

```
    private void login(){
    cookie = given()
            .baseUri("localhost:9000")
            .when()
            .formParam("username", "myUser")
            .formParam("password", "myPass")
            .formParam("realm", "realmParam")
            .post("/login")
            .then()
            .extract()
            .header("Set-Cookie");
}
```

i get the following error:

java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object

```
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:35)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:48)
at java_lang_String$trim.call(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport.mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash(PathSupport.groovy:28)
at io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport$mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:56)
at io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport$mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.getTargetPath(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1450)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor9.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:166)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.partiallyApplyPathParams(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1751)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor18.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.newFilterContext(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1151)
at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor32.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1720)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.applyPathParamsAndSendRequest(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1728)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:93)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:325)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1212)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1021)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:812)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:48)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:58)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:182)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:172)
at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.post(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
at discovery.utils.VMS.Requests.login(Requests.java:57)
at discovery.utils.VMS.Requests.<init>(Requests.java:16)
at discovery.utils.VMS.TestData.<init>(TestData.java:36)
at discovery.utils.VMS.TestData.<init>(TestData.java:30)
at discovery.users.EntitlementOverrideTest.overridenClientIsEntitledToAnyPackage(EntitlementOverrideTest.java:42)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

but I can't for the life of me figure out why! I've set a breakpoint on the line that throws and observed the input to that method, it turns out it is called many more times than I would expect from this test (the method concatenates 2 parts of a url) and the input that is actually defined in this failing test is processed without error. But then it is for some reason called a bunch of more times, on of which, invariably contains a null parameter and thus fails. Googling suggested there might be dependency-conflicts within my project, but I have been unable to find any.

To clarify, I'm not asking what a Nullpointer is, of that I am perfectly aware. Rather, it's the inner workings of rest-assured that has me confused.The nullpointer is merely the manifestation of my lacking understanding of this library's innards :)

whats going on?

Comment: which line is throwing the NPE?

Comment: @Stultuske The `post` one

Comment: well, the post line is the one in my code, but I digged deeper and was reffering to a line in the method `mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash` in io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport. (it's in the top of the stacktrace)

Comment: @Vanna I disagree, I know perfectly well what a nullpointer is, the trouble here is that it's occuring within a library whose internals I am not entirely familiar with

Comment: a bit like we don't know much of what your code is doing :)
it's hard to see what everything is (supposed to be) doing, but it would appear you'll need to check in that post method. somewhere there's a trim going on on a null, but there's no trim in the code you posted, so can't say where

Comment: I will try to add more details. and yes, trim is being called on null, as an effect of `mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash` being called with a null parameter. What confuses me is that the code pasted above is the first usage of restassured of this particular test, and the second parameter to `mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash`, apart from the null one, is definetly not coming from this test (it might well come from another test though, which would also be confusing, since while debugging I'm not (knowingly) running any other tests)

Comment: ah! figured it out!  kind of.. RestAssured is async, which is fair enough. but it is also mutable! 2 sequentiall calls to given() apparently returns the same mutable object, and my code overwrites some properties of that object that subsequent usages did not expect! this explains also why there were so many calls to to the methods and why the params looked funky to me

Comment: @AndersMartini : Did you mange to solve this ? I'd like to know the solution for this issue

Comment: @WilfredClement I did solve it, but I don't think you're gonna like the solution: I ended up swapping restAssured for OkHttp3 (with a homemade wrapper for our particular usage). lots of fun in a suite of ~1k it-tests.. ;)

if you have the same issue though, try forcing tests to run sequentially and remove any async code from your tests. This wasn't an option in my situation but it *should* solve the issue if you can do it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
I could fix it by removing `.baseUri("localhost:9000")` and use `.port(9000)` to set the port.