# Rest Assured - post - x-www-form-urlencoded - Cannot invoke method trim() on null object

Tags: rest, post, rest-assured

I am getting "Cannot invoke method trim() on null object" on this POST API.
URL : http://10.2.107.52:8080/auth/realms/Precisely/protocol/openid-connect/token
After digging more, I understood that this issue is coming from Rest assured internal library. Complete stack trace is

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method trim() on null object
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.NullObject.invokeMethod(NullObject.java:91)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaClassSite.call(PogoMetaClassSite.java:43)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.NullCallSite.call(NullCallSite.java:34)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:47)
        at java_lang_String$trim.call(Unknown Source)
        at io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport.mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash(PathSupport.groovy:28)
        at io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport$mergeAndRemoveDoubleSlash$0.callStatic(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallStatic(CallSiteArray.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:196)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callStatic(AbstractCallSite.java:216)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.getTargetPath(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1362)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:168)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.getPathParamPlaceholders(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1969)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:160)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.getRedundantNamedPathParams(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:2238)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:160)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.assertCorrectNumberOfPathParams(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy:1207)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:101)
        at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:323)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1217)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1041)
        at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:821)
        at io.restassured.internal.RequestSpecificationImpl.invokeMethod(RequestSpecificationImpl.groovy)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.call(PogoInterceptableSite.java:45)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoInterceptableSite.callCurrent(PogoInterceptableSite.java:55)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:51)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:156)
        at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:160)
```

```
                .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .formParam("grant_type", "password")
                .formParam("client_id", "OIDC-DIS-Agent")
                .formParam("scope", "openid")
                .formParam("username", base.getAuthUserName())
                .formParam("password", base.getAuthPassword())
                .when()
                .post(base.getAuthURL());
```

Also this is related to [`Nullpointer within io.restassured.internal.support.PathSupport` when using given.post()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45982958/nullpointer-within-io-restassured-internal-support-pathsupport-when-using-give) but I am not getting the solution here

Comment: Pls, provide more information, I don't see any `trim()` method here.

Comment: @lucas-nguyen-17 : I have edited the question with more details

Comment: It seems problem come from building the URI. I've debugged with your URL. No problem. Can you double check whether you set baseURL or re-use `RequestSpecificationImpl` instead of create a new instance?

Comment: I realised I had some other URL in config.properties with http:<URL> (without //) which was causing this issue, even before that URL is being used which is really weird. I corrected the URL and now everything is working fine. Thanks for your guidance and confirming that this code is correct @lucas-nguyen-17